# Error in getting number of pages for large files in php

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to find the number of pages in uploaded pdf file using this function getPDFPages(); it works fine with pdf files with less than 99 pages but returns nothing for larger files!
where is the problem?

Thanks

```
function getPDFPages($filepath)
{
   //$fp = (preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]/i", "", $filepath), "r");
   $fp = fopen(preg_replace('/^.+\\\\/', '', $filepath), "r");
    $max = 0;
    set_time_limit(0);
    if (!$fp) {
        return "Could not open file: $filepath";
    } else {
        while (!@feof($fp)) {
            $line = @fgets($fp, 255);
            if (preg_match('/\/Count [0-9]+/', $line, $matches)) {
                preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $matches[0], $matches2);
                if ($max < $matches2[0]) {
                    $max = trim($matches2[0]);
                    print_r($matches);
                    print_r($matches2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        @fclose($fp);
    }

    return $max;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't know the answer to your question but I think using an `@` symbol to suppress errors isn't a good practise in any situation. Start with that - from there turn on errors via PHP's built in `ini_set()`.

Comment: Thanks, removed @s and fixed ini.php , but nothing changed!

Comment: This means you could be flooding your memory in PHP, it's abit of a vague area but PHP isn't always as consistent it should be :S (sorry for late response btw - @work),.. Maybe you could try other methods but I don't think there will be a whole lot. I did some quick google on 'fopen limit' and found this to be possibly interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416080/does-fopen-have-a-size-limitation

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing string values, not numeric values. In a string comparison, "100" is less than "99" in the same way that "axx" is less than "zz" in dictionary order. If you convert the match to a number, it should work:

```
if ($max < (int)$matches2[0]) {
    $max = (int)trim($matches2[0]);
    print_r($matches);
    print_r($matches2);
    break;
}
```